# Minimal surfaces equations: global and local condition

Tags: differential-geometry, minimal-surfaces

A function being a minimal surface is a global condition, since is can be written as an integral over its domain of definition:

$$\int\int_\Delta \sqrt{1+\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\big)^2+\big(\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\big)^2}dxdy$$

However, Lagrange's minimal surfaces equation is only "local":

$$(1+q^2)r-2pqs+(1+p^2)t=0$$

(Using [Monge's notations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2485881/deducing-lagranges-minimal-surfaces-equation)).

Why does that happen? Why does this seemingly global condition translate into a local condition?